# How to send a PUT request using UnityWebRequest?

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, put

How do I send a PUT request using UnityWebRequest?

The PUT is being sent; `Uploaded!!` is being printed to the console. However, nothing is being updated. I think I'm formatting `myData` incorrectly.

The actual URL I'm trying to send the PUT to is formatted like... `http://servername.com/api/dogs/1/token=fndskajfdafdsf&cleanliness_level=20`

Sorry, I can't remember what that format is called.

This is the code that I have:

```
public string url = "http://servername.com/api/dogs/1";

.
.
.
void Start() {
StartCoroutine (UpdateDogs ("clean"));
}

IEnumerator UpdateDogs (string button)
    {
        byte[] myData;

        if (button == "feed") {
            myData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("?token=" + token + "&health_level=" + healthLevel);

        } else {
            myData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("?token=" + token + "&cleanliness_level=" + cleanlinessLevel);

        }

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put (url, myData)) {
            yield return www.Send ();

            if (www.isError) {
                Debug.Log ("PUT ERROR: " + www.error);
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Uploaded!!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing an & in the parameter string after the token.

```
token + "cleanliness_level=
```

Should be

```
token + "&cleanliness_level=
```

Similarly for the other possible parameters.

`myData` in `UnityWebRequest.Put` is only for http body data. It doesn't seem like you need that. Instead you should add your query parameters to the URL, like such:

```
public string url = "http://servername.com/api/dogs/1";

if (button == "feed") {
    url += "?token=" + token + "&health_level=" + healthLevel;
} else {
    url += "?token=" + token + "&cleanliness_level=" + cleanlinessLevel;
}

using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put (url, "dummy")) { // UnityWebRequest.Put requires a body, see comments below
    yield return www.Send ();

    if (www.isError) {
        Debug.Log ("PUT ERROR: " + www.error);
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Uploaded!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed the missing `&` and also the missing `?` in front of token. Made the adjustments and still not working. I also tried with an invalid token and didn't get a `www.error` so I don't think my PUT is being sent. I guess my confusion lies in...what am I supposed to put in `myData`?

Comment: I think you should have it all in the URL and nothing in ``myData``. Changed my answer to indicate it.

Comment: I get an error when I use `""` or `null` in place of `myData`. The error is: `ArgumentException: Cannot create a data handler without payload data` I ended up sending a random string like "Hello" and that seemed to have worked!

Comment: That's great @falafel. I will change my answer accordingly. That seems to be a limitation in UnityWebRequest, although the HTTP spec does indicate that a PUT should include an "enclosed entity", ie. a body.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a forward slash before token when you send it.

Try debugging what you actually send with

```
 Debug.Log (www.text);
```

Next advice is that maybe the error is with what code you use on the back end receiving the data.

Comment: UnityWebReqest doesn't have a `text`. How do I print out the URL sent? I don't see anything applicable on the UnityWebRequest page.

Comment: Printing `www.url.ToString()` gave me `http://servername.com/api/dogs/1`. This is the correct URL but I also have parameters which I put in `myData`.  Is that the correct place to put it? I added a `/` in front of token for posterity but am still not sending the PUT correctly.

Comment: I was mistaken about the use of www. I thought it handled similar to this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Comment: Problem might be with what you have on the back end receiving the data. Perhaps error is there

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Its not the backend; we tested our API and it's taking the PUT and updating the data correctly.